What is the protocol between an engine tuner and ECU?
I have a 2012 Yamaha WR450 and I really want to know the engine hours.  I have been unable to purchase the engine tuner 33D-H59C0-V1-00.
At this point, I am willing to try a hack to dump the ECU configuration, etc.  Does anybody know what the electrical signals might look like?  Would I be lucky enough to use CANBUS or is Yamaha some weird proprietary thing?  What do the command sets look like?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd be surprised if the ECU contained this information, personally.

Thanks for the welcome.  Where do you believe it would be stored?  Of course, I have never had the tuner, but I have the manual and it offers "engine running time" as a menu option (and time can be reset).  And this forms the basis of my quest.

I don't believe it'd be something which would be stored at all. But I don't know much about motorcycles.

For dirt bikes, the service intervals are specified by engine time.
